# Как создать форму, отправляющую POST-запрос на определенный адрес?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Моя форма

```
<%= form_with scope: :track, local: true do |t| %>
  <p>
    <%= t.text_field :name %>
  </p>

  <p>
    <%= t.text_area :description %>
  </p>

  <p>
    <%= t.text_field :genre %>
  </p>

  <p>
    <%= t.file_field :audiofile %>
  </p>

  <p>
    <%= t.submit %>
  </p>
<% end %>
```

отправляет в модель строку, все значения которой равны null

```
class TracksController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_track, only: [:show, :update, :destroy]

  def index
    @tracks = Track.all
    json_response(@tracks)
  end

  def new
    @track = Track.new
  end

  def find_by_genre
    @tracks = Track.where(genre: [params[:genre]])
    json_response(@tracks)
  end

  def create
    @track = Track.create!(track_params)
    json_response(@track, :created)
  end

  def show
    json_response(@track)
  end

  def update
    @track.update(track_params)
    head :no_content
  end

  def destroy
    @track.destroy
    head :no_content
  end

  private
    def track_params
      params.permit(:name, :description, :genre, :audiofile, :created_by)
    end

    def set_track
      @track = Track.find(params[:id])
    end
end
```

Я бы хотел в той же форме указать точный адрес, куда следует посылать значения из форм. Возможно ли это сделать?

Answer (score 0):

Какая удача, я почти сразу же нашел ответ на свой вопрос.
данную строку

```
<%= form_with scope: :track, local: true do |t| %>
```

необходимо заменить на следующее:

```
<%= form_with url: tracks_path do |form| %>
```

Именно таким образом и указывается url, куда будет отправлен post-запрос.